# How to dynamically format a string with a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

sorry for my bad english.

So, i'm trying to format a string with a matrix, example:

```
matrix = [ ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['u', 'v', 'w'], ['r', 's', 't'] ]
string = "H{}ll{} W{}rld"
```

The matrix will be generated depending how much '{}' the string has. The idea is use each array in the matrix for each '{}' in the string using .format():

```
string.format(*matrix)
```

The result is:

```
H['x', 'y', 'z']ll['u', 'v', 'w'] W['r', 's', 't']rld
```

So the best solution was:

```
for i in range(0, len(matrix[0])) :
    for j in range(0, len(matrix[1])) :
        for k in range(0, len(matrix[2])) :
            print(string.format(matrix[0][i], matrix[1][j], matrix[2][k]))
```

But the string and the matrix can be changed making this code useless, so i generated an array to use the elements as iterators:

```
iterators = [0] * len(matrix)
```

Then i made a recursive code to iterate the elements in iterators, the formating was:

```
string.format(string.format(matrix[0][iterators[0]], matrix[1][iterators[1]], matrix[2][iterators[2]]))
```

Then i tried to dinamically format:

```
string.format(*matrix[*iterators])
```

This don't worked (invalid syntax error), there's any way to make this work? I hope everything is clear. Thanks.

Comment: What's your desired output? "H**xyz**ll**uvw** W**rst**rld"?

Comment: what about something like `print [string.format(*m) for m in matrix]` ---> `['Hxlly Wzrld', 'Hullv Wwrld', 'Hrlls Wtrld']`. works when length of lists in matrix change.

Comment: i will try this too, thx

Comment: Hi @KobePol if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a cartesian product and is beautifully implemented in itertools

```
import itertools

matrix = [ ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['u', 'v', 'w'], ['r', 's', 't'] ]
string = "H{}ll{} W{}rld"
for group in itertools.product(*matrix):
    print(string.format(*group))
```

Comment: that worked really well, thx! i should search more about cartesian products

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the output as "H**xyz**ll**uvw** W**rst**rld", you could use this:

```
string.format(*[''.join(line) for line in matrix])
```

First, you flat the matrix by producing a list of strings `['xyz', 'uvw', 'rst']`, then you unpack this list with the `*` operator so you can use the `format` function.

Comment: this isnt the result that i was looking for, but you gave an interesting answer, i didnt know 'for' can be used this way, thx :)